# Power Virtual Agent - Search Knowledge Flow Failing

Tags: power-virtual-agents

I have setup a PVA according to [Teams - Power Virtual Agent - Hornbill](https://wiki.hornbill.com/index.php?title=Teams_Power_Virtual_Agent), but when I trigger the "I need help" topic, it fails with:

> [24/12/21 12:05] Hornbill Virtual Agent Sorry, the bot can't talk for
> a while. It's something the bot's owner needs to address. Error code:
> 2003. Conversation ID: a:1sRpdKJmBlAwDCW_UxiSZQu1EwZTezthuB0bMKqsIUFkm063EHs_yW1AOwa2TJBKWe1mruDht_-bRHbehJ7xheba3ZSqxdJDWqy3vODCetFwaHv73q-orLwBOsf-I6d40.
> Time (UTC): 12/24/2021 12:05:50 PM.

Having done some investigation, the issue appears to be due to the search knowledge flow failing with the following error:

> Unable to process template language expressions in action
> 'Parse_JSON_-_Content' inputs at line '1' and column '2516': 'Required
> property 'content' expects a value but got null. Path ''.'.

Although the HTTP step in the flow succeeds, I believe that the error is caused because the following is returned:

```
<message>Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property &apos;siteName&apos; of null</message>
```

Full output below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<methodCallResult status="fail">
    <state>
        <code>0207</code>
        <service>apps</service>
        <operation>chatbotKnowledgeSearch</operation>
        <error>/apps/com.hornbill.servicemanager/flowcode/fc_ops/chatbotKnowledgeSearch.js(46): error X1001: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property &apos;siteName&apos; of null</error>
        <flowcodeError>
            <where>Execute</where>
            <filename>/apps/com.hornbill.servicemanager/flowcode/fc_ops/chatbotKnowledgeSearch.js</filename>
            <lineNumber>46</lineNumber>
            <columnPos>18</columnPos>
            <message>Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property &apos;siteName&apos; of null</message>
            <errorCode>1001</errorCode>
        </flowcodeError>
    </state>
</methodCallResult>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error:

```
        <message>Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property &apos;siteName&apos; of null</message>
```

It stated your content of siteName is empty. Are you sure your passing variable is the right name? Maybe you are passing Website instead of siteName?